# Space elevator from Earth to Moon with multiple temporary anchors

Tags: space-elevators

Would it be possible to build a space elevator from the surface of the earth to the Moon with the following characteristics?

- It would be attached to the Moon, using it as counterweight.
- On the
  surface of the earth, it would anchor on different bases that were
  built following the orbit plane of the Moon.

It would work like this: when reaching a base, the elevator would lower a cable that holds the end of the elevator, anchors it to a fixed base, stays there until the looseness of the lower cable is lost, then it detaches from the base and "flies" to the next base.

How feasible would this be? Are there any examples on the sci-fi literature? I remember the Cradle from Seveneves, but it used the orbital ring for moving it.

Comment: Are you suggesting the cable does a sort of "walking motion" across Earth, from anchor point to anchor point? (If so, I think L.Dutch's answer is a misinterpretation.)

Comment: anchoring at different bases for a millisecond while moving at faster than the speed of sound. what would be the point. I suggest instead you look up skyhooks.

Comment: sounds like a great way to crash the Moon on the Earth

Comment: @armand if it can do that, I'd like to invest in the cable's manufacturer, because they have developed an exceptionally high-quality product :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the cable manufacturer, the rocket that managed to take it to space, the wielders who managed to attach it to the Moon... we're in cloud kookooland from the get go so you can choose what you handwave and what mode of failure you think is the funniest. Although a 400.000 km cable snapping and falling back to Earth is fun, it lacks the spark of the Moon crashing, IMHO.

Comment: There's also not a constant "orbital plane of the moon" relative to the Earth's surface.  The moon's orbit is inclined at 5° to the ecliptic plane,  and the direction of that inclination precesses with a period of about 18.5 years. As a result, the inclination of the moon's orbit to the earth's equator ranges between 28° and 18° over this period of time.

Comment: "Anchor" does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 40):

Totally unfeasible. For a detailed explanation, you can read this episode of [What if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/).

In short:

> In real life, we can't put a metal pole between the Earth and the Moon. The end of the pole near the Moon would be pulled toward the Moon by the Moon's gravity, and the rest of it would be pulled back down to the Earth by the Earth's gravity. The pole would be torn in half.

> Another problem with this plan. The Earth's surface spins faster than the Moon goes around, so the end that dangled down to the Earth would break off if you tried to connect it to the ground. [...] Asking how fast the pole is moving relative to the surface is effectively the same as asking what the "ground speed" of the Moon is. This is tricky to calculate, because the Moon's ground speed varies over time in a complicated way. Luckily for us, it doesn't vary that much—it's usually somewhere between 390 and 450 m/s, or a little over Mach 1—so figuring out the precise value isn't necessary.

[image]

> There's one more problem: The Moon doesn't always stay the same distance from Earth. Its orbit takes it closer and farther away. It's not a big difference, but it's enough that the bottom 50,000 km of your fire station pole would be squished against the Earth once a month.

To put it in Randall's words

> That thing is definitely a safety hazard.

Comment: Not downvoted because I haven't received confirmation from OP, but I believe you've badly misinterpreted the question. I think OP describes a cable that performs a walking motion across Earth, matching the Moon's orbit.

Comment: @BMF "a walking cable" which is moving a Mach 1 is equally unfeasible

Comment: @BMF You should click the "What If" link. Cable vs pole makes no difference.

Comment: @L.Dutch things move at Mach 1 through atmosphere all the time. What's the problem? (I mean I don't disagree with the conclusion; It's impractical. There are better ways to use tethers for lunar transfer. But it doesn't strike me as *totally impossible*.)

Comment: Having fixed stations is further complicated by the Moon's orbital inclination, the precession of said orbit and to a lesser extent the Moon's libration around its tilted axis.

Comment: @MichaelK cable vs pole is not at all the relevant part of their comment. They were replying to this ("Another problem with this plan. The Earth's surface spins faster than the Moon goes around, so the end that dangled down to the Earth would break off if you tried to connect it to the ground") paragraph.

Comment: It should be noted: 1) A proper space elevator goes out 44,000 miles, a good ways to the moon 2) the moon can also have its own space elevator too, eliminating yet more of the total distance and 3) you can climb to the end of the Earth space elevator and let go which can put you on track to head towards the terminus of the moon's elevator, docking there, and taking that back down to the surface. There's no need for a direct connection between the two bodies.

Comment: @MS It makes no difference, the problems are exactly the same, because at that length, a pole and a cable are essentially the same, the difference in stiffness being entirely negligible. So they can reply to that one little bit all they want, the idea is still dead on arrival.

Comment: @MichaelK again, their comment has nothing to do with the differences between poles and cables

Comment: There are numerous problems with this idea. Dutch lists a couple of them, then references the What If that goes into more detail. When you're talking about things that are a hundred thousand miles long, there is no meaningful difference between a pole and a cable, except that we could vary the thickness of the cable more easily. At this scale, a cable is a cluster of poles.

Comment: @L.Dutch  I think the top of the cable moves at mach 1; the bottom attaches to a place for some time and then travels at mach 2 to catch up.

Answer (score 9):

**Not feasible**

Cool idea, but it has some serious problems.

1. The moon wobbles, the Earth wobbles, weather causes the permanent end of the cable hanging mid-atmosphere to wobble. That thing would be all over the place and destroying everything it came in contact with. Birds. Planes. Superman. Everything.
2. Because that cable is seriously wobbling, the stress on the cable and, more importantly, the stress on the connection at the moon would be under *horrific* stress. Yes, we could handwave this by claiming the cable is unbreakable and the anchor on the moon was a bar that pierced the moon through and through. But the heat, the stress, the vibration... And we're not talking about a minor mass but one that's very noticeable to the moon. If the anchor weren't ripped off of (or out of) the moon, there would be at least two points of heat that would make transit a serious challenge: the anchor point and a standing wave point somewhere along the cable.
3. I'm not convinced that, once attached on an anchor on Earth, the cable could stay in place for longer than a fraction of a second before it would get torn away, or would destabilize the anchor.

**But, maybe if we modify your idea a bit...**

*Let's build the Earth's first megastructure!*

Have you ever seen those tracks hanging from the ceiling in hospitals for the curtains around beds? Hold that thought.

Let's build a track around the Earth that matches the average orbital path around the Earth. I'm ignoring all the nasty calculations due to the Earth's axial tilt, the moon's orbital inclination, etc. It won't simply be around the equator. It will have of necessity levitating magnetics, dynamic power generation!, and some of the best material science humanity has ever seen.

Now, let's build an anchor on the moon with a high quality (for the sake of conversation) spring-loaded spool that can maintain the tension on the cable as the moon and Earth wobble.

As you can imagine, that cable will be bookin' around the Earth at tremendous speed! Curiously, it will be traveling counter to the rotation of the Earth (because it's actually moving more slowly than the Earth). That's going to have consequences for weather (heat, wind, etc.) and consequences for airplanes, balloons, bottle rockets, space stations, etc. Let's ignore all that.

Obviously you can't just have an elevator. It's no big deal for people and goods on the moon where the anchor isn't moving (other than back and forth through the carriage... but that's just a design issue. Kinda cool getting on the carriage and watching the cable sliding through it...). But here on Earth you can't just stop the carriage and step on like a Ferris Wheel. Take your arm off, that would.

Let there be cars along the rim of the track all along the track that allow for goods and people to be accelerated to and decelerated from the velocity of the cable. Let the connection between said cars and the cable carriage be ridged and well protected 'cause hundreds of meters per second is way, way, way beyond hurricane force winds.

Finally, remember when I mentioned dynamic power generation? This whole process could power itself and probably several major cities (if not a whomping lot more) so long as the draw didn't cause measurable braking.

Boom, baby.

*And I'm handwaving the effects of wind passing along a long string anchored at two points. Look up "standing waveforms." The good folks in that carriage are in for the ride of their lives. Better have air sickness bags.*

*BTW, considering the somewhat fanciful movies involving megastructures around the Earth in the last ten years, I'm claiming the movie rights for this one. It's no more silly than any of the others and has much more dramatic appeal. Let's see Alita climb this cable! :-)*

Answer (score 9):

**Frame Challenge: you don't need (nor do you want) an elevator connecting the Earth to the Moon.  You just need an elevator on each one.**

The primary difficulty of getting between the Earth and the Moon is getting out of Earth's gravity well ([obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/681/) as well as a helpful [solar system map](https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/29cxi6/i_made_a_deltav_subway_map_of_the_solar_system/) that is shockingly not an XKCD).  Space elevators help with this because they let you get out of most of the gravity well of a planet/moon without [falling victim to the rocket equation](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html), wherein you need to accelerate your vehicle and all of its fuel (see https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30469/894 for more discussion and other benefits).

Once at geostationary orbit of Earth, it would take a much smaller amount of fuel to get from there to the Moon than to get off the planet in the first place.  You could even have the top of the space elevator equipped with rail guns to accelerate capsules at the Moon to further reduce the fuel they need (as long as you have some way to offset the momentum imparted on the station).

Similarly, you can build a space elevator on the Moon to reduce the energy needed to land on the Moon and/or take off from the Moon, although both of these are far less energy intensive due to the small size of the Moon's gravity well.  If you have elevators on both sides with sufficiently powerful launch equipment on top of each one, and equipment to capture and de-accelerate launched capsules, you could theoretically get between the Earth and Moon in an inert capsule (one with no thrusters of its own), although having a few thrusters for emergency corrections would be much safer. (See [Zero energy transfer between Earth and Moon with space elevators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/247832/83464) for a discussion on the scientific plausibility of a thruster-free transit.)

Take the [Saturn V](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-48907836) for example.  A space elevator on Earth alone does the job of the first two stages and some of the third stage of the Saturn V.  That gets rid of [over 90%](https://apollo11space.com/how-many-stages-did-saturn-v-have/) of the mass/fuel of the rocket.  Add a space elevator on the Moon and you need even less mass because you don't need the fuel to get back off the Moon, or the fuel to accelerate that fuel (etc.).  At this point, you could get back and forth between the Earth and moon with something smaller than the [Apollo command and service module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module) (it would be smaller since it doesn't need to carry a lunar lander with it).  Adding ship launchers and catchers to the tops of the space elevators saves you even more.  At this point, you can spend some of that savings on extra space for cargo or passenger comfort.

Two elevators is vastly easier to build than a mega Earth-Moon connector.  It doesn't need to adjust to the Earth's rotation or the varying Earth-Moon distance.  It also uses a fraction of the cable length; you only need enough cable to reach from Earth to geostationary orbit and [from the Moon to the Earth-Moon L1 point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_space_elevator#Location), which is about 100,000 km of total cable rather than 250,000 km of the whole distance.  On top of that, the two-elevator model is more generally useful.  If you bring a ship with engines up the elevator, you can go other places, such as on satellite launch/repair missions or asteroid mining.  And, once you expand beyond Earth, you are much better set up to have a transit network with elevators on other planets.  You just need to build some larger ship launchers at the elevator tops to be able to reach Mars.

Comment: Minor nitpick - the moon is tidally locked so a "selenostationary" orbit isn't possible; you'd have to use the L1 or L2 points, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_space_elevator

Comment: @10762409 Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous categories of "it won't work" for this question.

1. Structural

If you think a space elevator from Earth is edge-of-possibility technology, then this is impossible technology. There is no known substance that can survive the tension, at any thickness, of a pole/cable this long.

2. Force management

Let's say you make it out of exotic unobtanium, or hard-light, or similar hand-wavium. The forces aren't balanced the way they would be for a beanstalk. You'd have to move the Moon out a bit to keep the weight of the cable from pulling the Moon out of orbit over time.

3. Atmospheric drag

If it were just a solid pole, it would be moving at Mach 1, but we're working with handwavium, so we have options. Let's consider this one: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.29010

That model has the end of the cable moving in an oval. The oval dips into the atmosphere, things grab it, and then it pulls the objects upward. It's actually a complex but feasible method of allowing the tether to be shorter, but we shouldn't limit our imagination like that.

We could make the end of the tether dip into the atmosphere, following the movement of the Earth, then pull up and move at twice that while out of the atmosphere in order to compensate. It would be more of a sky-hook than a space elevator, but we take what we can get, right? It means that the end wouldn't be in the atmosphere for the supersonic sections of its flight.